# Centering buttons within a div container

Tags: html, css, button, layout

I'd really appreciate some help on an issue i'm having.

For reference: http://trs-studios.com/test

I'm trying to get the 3 boxes (side to side) to align to the center of the page.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a class="btn btn-large" href="URL TO YOUR SUBSITE" target="_blank"></i> MEDIA</a>
<div class="spacer"/>
<a class="btn btn-large" href="URL TO YOUR SUBSITE" target="_blank"></i> STUDIO</a>
<div class="spacer"/>
<a class="btn btn-large" href="URL TO YOUR SUBSITE" target="_blank"></i> DESIGN</a>
</div>
```

Css for wrapper

```
.wrapper {  
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Css for spacer

```
.spacer {
    display: inline;
    margin: 50px 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: div is not self closing tag

Comment: ..and divs as 'spacers' are just plain **bad**

Comment: Thank you, closing the divs just as Morpheus and LorDex suggested centered the buttons.

Comment: Paulie_D, can you elaborate on why it's bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget those spacing divs, HTML is not for styling.

Using `display: inline-block` on your links, you can simply put margin on them.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="btn btn-large" href="URL TO YOUR SUBSITE" target="_blank">MEDIA</a>
    <a class="btn btn-large" href="URL TO YOUR SUBSITE" target="_blank">STUDIO</a>
    <a class="btn btn-large" href="URL TO YOUR SUBSITE" target="_blank">DESIGN</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    text-align: center; 
}

.wrapper .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px 25px;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/gSEQQ/1/)